# How does search engine give me the answer I want?

Tags: caching, search-engine

Each time, when we type the key-words in Google, how does Google give us its answers?
I want to know the process of how Google process our requests.

Personally, I assume that:

1.there are a huge amount of queries sent to Google, in order to respond ASAP, Google gotta have some kinda `distributed system`, right?

2.also, I think there are some kind of `cache systems` to speed up Google's response speed, right?

3.If cache indeed exists, `what is stored in that cache`? Could it be some kind of `<key, value>` pair? Cuz I guess that, it's `<key-words, url>`. But would be it be too expensive to cache `url` directly, because each url will probably take up many memory, right?

**UPDATE:**

After skimming the keynote suggested by @Gregory Pakosz, I wondering what the `Cache Server` is responsible for and what the Cache Server caches?

[image]

Comment: I think this question is to general to be answered here

Comment: @ulvung I would have said the same if I didn't look for group varint encoding in the past and know about that keynote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeff Dean's 2009 keynote: [Challenges in Building Large-Scale Information Retrieval Systems](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en//people/jeff/WSDM09-keynote.pdf) gives a pretty nice overview of how Google works.

Comment: I just skimmed the doc, wondering what the `Cache Server` is responsible for. Is it responsible for caching the frequently queried words and their urls?